# DateFormatter to convert date

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting date in millisecond from server:

```
 dob = 1344364200000;
```

I am converting it into date and I got :

2012-08-07 18:29:20 +0000

When I set this date to date picker It is showing me **August-7-2012**

This is my dateformater:

```
     df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];
```

And server side date is **August-8-2012...**

Comment: Google "UNIX epoch converter" -- the above timestamp is indeed Tue, 07 Aug 2012 18:30:00 GMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. There was logical mistake to convert millisecond into date. To convert millisecond to second I have taken float variable to store second and taken double variable to store millisecond from server that's why it was giving me difference of 40 second in actual date and converted date. Then I took both variable in double and problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

If your server and the client are located in different time zones, there will be time difference which could result in the server and client showing different dates. Convert all date times to UTC before communication (from server to client as well as client to server) and adjust according to local timezone before displaying the date time.

Comment: I got this : 2012-08-07 18:29:20 +0000 when I convert into date. This is also 2012-08-08 but I dont know how to convert it into that. When I converted I got 2012-08-07

Comment: i did not understand what exactly you are trying to say in the comment. Is your date in millisecond already in UTC? if not try converting it to UTC on the server.

Comment: i got solution there was mistake in my logic...you can remove your answer...I want to remove this question

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it as the right answer.. deleting the question and answer would mean something wrong was posted which is not the case.